# Why does ubuntu not see my maximum monitor resolution?

Tags: xorg, multiple-monitors, display, display-resolution, amd-graphics

for some reason, the xrandr on my computer does not see the maximum resolution of my monitor. He writes that the minimum, current and maximum resolution are the same. I have a  [Radeon R7 240](https://www.amd.com/en/support/graphics/amd-radeon-r7-series/amd-radeon-r7-200-series/amd-radeon-r7-240) video card. Today I installed drivers on it from the official site. Also, an X server flashed off today, I don’t know how, but I restored it. Also now, instead of the standard ubuntu GUI, I started using the kubunt GUI. On the standard GUI, everything was fine, the resolution was correct. I forgot to clarify that the TV is still connected to the video card, and it was displayed on the standard GUI, but now it isn’t. I didn’t find the answer in Google.

P.S. The maximum resolution of the monitor is 1280x800 (so that everything is displayed correctly).

Output of `xrandr` :

```
my-username@my-machine-id:~/Загрузки(Downloads)/lxde-common-0.99.2$ xrandr
xrandr: Failed to get size of gamma for output default                                                                                         
Screen 0: minimum 1024 x 768, current 1024 x 768, maximum 1024 x 768
default connected primary 1024x768+0+0 0mm x 0mm
   1024x768      76.00*
```

Edited: When I wrote "cubuntu GUI", I meant kubuntu GUI, kubuntu-desktop installed via apt-get. I have Ubuntu 18.04 desktop. I don't use virtualization. My model of monitor is Acer K192HQL. On Windows in AIDA64 in supported resolutions there is 1280x800. I have a TV connected to the video card via HDMI and a monitor connected to the same video card through VGA.

Edited 2: When I create and add a new mode with `xrandr` to my monitor, the system says that I have chosen too high a resolution that my monitor or video card does not support (I'm not on Linux now, I can’t say for sure)

Comment: To start with: 1) did you mean 'KDE Desktop' when you typed 'cubunt GUI'? 2) Which version of Linux have you installed  (Ubuntu server, Ubuntu desktop, Kubuntu, Lubuntu, Xubuntu, Ubuntu MATE, et al.) , and which release number? 3) Are you using virtualization, and if so, which package? 4) What's the make and model of your monitor? 5) Is it a TV/monitor, or do you have a TV _and_ a monitor? Please click [edit] and add that vital information to your question so all the facts we need are in the question. Please do not use Add Comment.

Comment: are you using a VGA cable? If yes then buy a new cable, the old one is broken so the [OS can't get resolution information from the DDC channel](https://superuser.com/q/835656/241386). There are a lot of similar issues: [Resolution 1920 x 1080 is not available for external monitor](https://superuser.com/q/193703/241386), [My computer doesn't recognize the monitor's resolution on some VGA cables, what's going on?](https://superuser.com/q/943139/241386), [Resolution 1920 x 1080 is not available for external monitor](https://superuser.com/q/193703/241386)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My graphics card driver has not been fully installed. I found a video on YouTube when someone talked about installing drivers on AMD graphics cards. Here is the video: [How to Install AMD GPU Radeon Driver in Debian](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gOwMe_UYMdM).

Edited: Output of `xrandr`:

```
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 1280 x 800, maximum 16384 x 16384
HDMI-0 connected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
   1280x720      60.32 +  60.00    50.00    50.00    59.94  
   1920x1080     60.00    50.00    59.94  
   1920x1080i    60.00    50.00    59.94  
   2880x576i     50.00  
   1280x1024     75.02  
   1024x768      75.03    70.07    60.00  
   1440x480      60.00    59.94  
   800x600       72.19    75.00    60.32    56.25  
   720x576       50.00  
   720x480       60.00    59.94  
   720x480i      60.00    59.94  
   640x480       75.00    72.81    66.67    60.00    59.95    59.94  
   720x400       70.08  
DVI-0 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
VGA-0 connected primary 1280x800+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 410mm x 230mm
   1366x768      59.79 +
   1280x800      59.81* 
   1280x720      60.00  
   1024x768      75.03    70.07    60.00  
   832x624       74.55  
   800x600       72.19    75.00    60.32    56.25  
   640x480       75.00    72.81    66.67    59.94  
   720x400       70.08
```

Edited 2: I turned off the TV in the system settings.